# Magento 2.2 Product Images Duplicated

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, bulk-products-update

I have a lot of **SKU's** and a lot of SKU's share some **pictures**.

For eg -  Product A, B and C have 2 common photos. When I upload the common photos through the panel, It uploads the same image to the server again and again by adding **_1** in the file name.

Also tried using **bulk upload** but **get errors**. I don't want this **duplicating of photos** as I have a lot of SKU's and photos and my server won't be able to handle all that data.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Its core functionality of magento. If one image(a.jpeg) have uploaded for some product(A). Again we upload the same image(a.jpg) for another product its uploaded (a_1.jpg). Its the default core functionality of magento.

Comment: I understand. But this isnt feasible for me and i would need an alternative.

Comment: Refer this link http://www.pixelpaul.net/magento-share-images-on-more-products/ . It would help you to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known core bug in Magento 2.2+

Github issues here:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14398
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21885

And pull requests here:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/21146
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/21855

I'm using the first PR successfully in production, and patched using cweagans/composer-patches after every `composer install`.

Keep in mind both PRs have limitations and haven't been tested properly.

Comment: How do you use the PR?

Comment: @user2240778 you'll need a developer to create a patch for your installation

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue in Magento 2.3.2 by adding second parameter to uploadMediaFiles method as **true** in magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php line 1799.

`$uploadedFile = $this->uploadMediaFiles($columnImage, true);`

You need a preference or a plugin to achieve this.